# Hiding TaskBar from a process (c#)

Tags: c#, taskbar

In my application, I want to hide the windows TaskBar and StartMenuButton when my process is started and want to restore it when it exits.

I can do this using:

```
IntPtr  startButtonHwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0xC017, null);
IntPtr  taskBarHwnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "");

ShowWindow(taskBarHwnd, 0);
ShowWindow(startButtonHwnd, 0);
```

and this is working fine for me.
Now I see a case where, if my process is crashed for some reason or is FORCIBLY killed by user, I won't be able to restore the TaskBar.

Is there any method of restoring it for these TWO (crash and killed) cases?

I am also interacting with Windows Gadget and I show a Gadget window when some button is clicked in my application, so I can not use properties like `Form.TopMost = true` & `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`

Thanks,

Vikram

Comment: You should be careful with this way if explorer.exe is terminated/restarted.

Comment: IMHO you cannot: both cases can't be _trapped_ by your app. You could limit crashes managing exceptions, but if user kills your app, what can you do? You're not notified of this...

Comment: @Marco: If it's really important, a background process. (not that it can't be terminated...)

Comment: This seems all wrong. Just show your app full screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can cater for most crashes by putting the restore code in a global exception handler. You can do this by setting up an [unhandled exception handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

```
  AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
  currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);


static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    ShowWindow(taskBarHwnd, 0);
    ShowWindow(startButtonHwnd, 0);
}
```

This won't cater for the case where the program is killed.